# Drupal 7 - Migrate files into custom file type

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, migration

I am trying to migrate files into a custom filetype with a lot of custom defined fields. However they seem to be getting migrated in the `document` filetype rather than into my custom created filetype.

I'm using the `MigrateDestinationFile` as my destination like this:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile();
```

I've tried to map the `type` like [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115470/migrate-into-custom-file-type) suggested like this:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('type')->defaultValue('custom_file_type');
```

This solution doesn't work, when checking the mappable fields for the `MigrateDestinationFile` there is no `type` field specified so I think this is the reason why that solution doesn't work.

If some one could point me to an example of how to migrate into a custom file type that would be highly appreciated. Maybe I'm using the wrong `destination`? Or did I miss something very obvious.

The other part of the migration doesn't matter for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I had two issues. The first one being that when we created the file type we called it `file` which for some reason you can't set as a migrate destination since it's already default in the `MigrateDestinationFile` constructor (see code below).

```
From file.inc:544

/**
 * Basic initialization
 *
 * @param array $options
 *  Options applied to files.      
 */
public function __construct($bundle = 'file', $file_class = 'MigrateFileUri', $options = array()) {
  parent::__construct('file', $bundle, $options);
  $this->fileClass = $file_class;
}
```

Second issue was the mapping to the field *bundle* itself. I simply had to set the correct destination like this after re-creating the file type with a different name:

```
$this->destination = new MigrateDestinationFile('product_download');
```

After doing this the migrated files where created in the correct content type rather than the `document` file type.